# Application_Error event in global.asax not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-filter

I'm having an issue where the `Application_Error` event does not seem to fire when I explicitly throw a page-level exception.

My Global.asax.cs file is as follow:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            CustomExceptionClass.BootstrapEnterpriseLibrary();  
    }

    // Event handler that passes all exceptions not in a catch statement 
    // to the handler

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        CustomExceptionClass.HandleException(ex);
        Server.ClearError();
    }
}

public class ExceptionPublisherExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
        var exception = exceptionContext.Exception;
        CustomExceptionClass.HandleException(exception);
    }
}

public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, 
        ref Message fault)
    {
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        CustomExceptionClass.HandleException(error);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My web.config file has `<customErrors mode="Off">`.

My filterconfig looks like the following:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ExceptionPublisherExceptionFilter());
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

I have tried the following fixes:

- Change `customErrors` to on or off
- Implement a new filter and add it to filterconfig

Whenever I throw an exception in VS, I try to step into it, but it just keeps on running. Does anyone know why `Application_Error` isn't being fired?

**Edit**: It looks like the scope affects whether `Application_Error` gets called. So the question is really, why `Application_Error` isn't being called at the page-level.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for but it served a higher question of effectively implementing global exception handling in an asp.net application.

I used Application_Error to handle all of the application level exceptions, and followed, to the letter, the instructions provided [here][1]


  [1]: http://davidjs.com/2014/04/handle-exceptions-in-asp-net-iis/

This allowed me to implement http exception handling and filtering. It effectively solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were testing this with an `HttpResponseException` it turns out that those are ignored by `ApiExceptionHandler` and derived classes [by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) and will never result in `Application_Error` firing. Switch to another `Exception` type to address the issue.